# Graph facet graph with two sets of data - multivariable (original dataset combines two dataset)

Tags: r, dataframe, graph, facet

I have been trying to find some resources similar to this, but my current dataset looks like this:

| lwg_date | bon_date | lwg_length | bon_length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| March | April | 1 | 31 |
| March | April | 10 | 14 |
| March | April | 12 | 12 |
| March | May | 19 | 11 |
| April | May | 5 | 17 |
| April | May | 19 | 41 |
| April | June | 55 | 24 |
| April | June | 13 | 22 |
| August | Sept | 21 | 17 |
| August | Sept | 15 | 18 |

I previously had thought that rearranging the dataset would help me create facet graphs but later realized that it would still be quite difficult, and I am having a hard time imagining it now too.

*The end result should be graphs based on months (ie. March graph, April graph, May graph) where each graph has two histograms (LWG, BON) overlaying an x-axis of length and y-axis of the count of the respective lwg/bon data.*

The issue I kept encountering was understanding how to facet wrap it by months. Perhaps I been going about in circles with this but I have tried reorganizing lwg_month and bon_month column together (which got messy), add both variables in facet wrap (got confused).

I would be open to suggestions; thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
          lwg_date = c("March","March","March",
                       "March","April","April","April","April","August",
                       "August"),
          bon_date = c("April","April","April",
                       "May","May","May","June","June","Sept","Sept"),
        lwg_length = c(1L, 10L, 12L, 19L, 5L, 19L, 55L, 13L, 21L, 15L),
        bon_length = c(31L, 14L, 12L, 11L, 17L, 41L, 24L, 22L, 17L, 18L)
) %>%

  # reshape into    type | date | length
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = c("type", ".value"), names_sep = "_") %>%

  # turn date into ordered factor
  mutate(date = ifelse(date == "Sept", "September", date),
         date = factor(date, levels = month.name)) %>%

  # plot histograms
  ggplot(aes(length, fill = type)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 5) +
  facet_wrap(~date)
```